# Java FX: Getting and editing an object from Observable List

Tags: list, object, javafx, observablelist

I know about the method list.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();  and its index version, but heres my problem:

I have setup a List in my GUI which holds Objects of a class Person. In my GUI theres also Text Fields with the attributes of that class (Name,Street,Age etc).

What I did so far is implement a method clickList() which will fill the attribute fields with the data from the selected object in the listview. So the user can edit them from here and press another button which should then update those attributes.

I also setup so you can create a new object from the text form by doing this inside my "OK" Button inside my Controller:

```
     ObservableList<Person> items = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
     items.add(new Person(tf_vn.getText(), tf_nn.getText(),tf_strasse.getText(), tf_plz.getText(), tf_ort.getText(),genderChoice, sliderAge.getValue());
      list.setItems(items);
```

However what im struggling with is the editing of the already existing Person. Can someone give me some pointers? I know I can get the selected object index but how do I work with it? Basicly I just need to find a way to do something like selectedObject.setAge(),selectedObject.setName() etc

I looked through all the getSelectionModel() methods but didnt find a solution, im sure there is a easy one....

Thanks in advance !

Comment: In you `clickList` method the `Person` instance and it's index seems to be available which means you can store this info to use it later when clicking the other `Button`. If `Person` is mutable, you can simply call the setters with the values from the `TextField`s. Otherwise create a new instance of `Person` by passing the values from the `TextField`s to it's constructor and replacing the element at the index that you're editing with the new `Person` instance.

Comment: How would I go about replacing the person instance at my index with the newly created one?

About the first suggestino, its mutable. But how would I call the setters on the index object?

Comment: are you using generics? `ListView<Person> list = new ListView<>();`

Comment: @sontiyo It just modify the `items` list the way you would modify an ordinary `List<Person>`: `list.getItems().set(index, newPerson);`. As for the first suggestion: Assuning you stored the `Person` you're editing in a field `editedPerson`, call the methods on this instance... But in this case your problem probably comes down to not using `Person` as type parameter for your `ListView`...

Answer (score 1):

This way you can reach selectedObject's methods

```
ListView<Person> l = new ListView<>();
...
l.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().setFirstName("new name");
l.refresh();
```

a full example may look like;

```
package so;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TableViewSample extends Application {

    private TableView<Person> table = new TableView<Person>();
    private final ObservableList<Person> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
            new Person("Jacob", "Smith", "jacob.smith@example.com"),
            new Person("Isabella", "Johnson", "isabella.johnson@example.com"),
            new Person("Ethan", "Williams", "ethan.williams@example.com"),
            new Person("Emma", "Jones", "emma.jones@example.com"),
            new Person("Michael", "Brown", "michael.brown@example.com"));
    final HBox hb = new HBox();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        Scene scene = new Scene(new Group());
        stage.setTitle("Table View Sample");
        stage.setWidth(450);
        stage.setHeight(550);

        final Label label = new Label("Address Book");
        label.setFont(new Font("Arial", 20));

        // table.setEditable(true);

        TableColumn<Person, String> firstNameCol = new TableColumn<>("First Name");
        firstNameCol.setMinWidth(100);
        firstNameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>("firstName"));

        TableColumn<Person, String> lastNameCol = new TableColumn<>("Last Name");
        lastNameCol.setMinWidth(100);
        lastNameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>("lastName"));

        TableColumn<Person, String> emailCol = new TableColumn<>("Email");
        emailCol.setMinWidth(200);
        emailCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>("email"));

        table.setItems(data);
        table.getColumns().addAll(firstNameCol, lastNameCol, emailCol);

        final TextField addFirstName = new TextField();
        addFirstName.setPromptText("First Name");
        addFirstName.setMaxWidth(firstNameCol.getPrefWidth());
        final TextField addLastName = new TextField();
        addLastName.setMaxWidth(lastNameCol.getPrefWidth());
        addLastName.setPromptText("Last Name");
        final TextField addEmail = new TextField();
        addEmail.setMaxWidth(emailCol.getPrefWidth());
        addEmail.setPromptText("Email");

        final Button addButton = new Button("Add");
        addButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent e) {

                if (table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem() != null) {
                    table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().setFirstName(addFirstName.getText());
                    table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().setLastName(addLastName.getText());
                    table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().setEmail(addEmail.getText());
                    table.refresh();
                } else {
                    data.add(new Person(addFirstName.getText(), addLastName.getText(), addEmail.getText()));
                    addFirstName.clear();
                    addLastName.clear();
                    addEmail.clear();
                }

            }
        });

        table.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((e, o, n) -> {
```

//              addFirstName.clear();
//              addLastName.clear();
//              addEmail.clear();

```
            if (n != null) {

                addFirstName.setText(n.getFirstName());
                addLastName.setText(n.getLastName());
                addEmail.setText(n.getEmail());

                addButton.setText("Edit");

            }
            else {

                addButton.setText("Add");

            }

        });

        hb.getChildren().addAll(addFirstName, addLastName, addEmail, addButton);
        hb.setSpacing(3);

        final VBox vbox = new VBox();
        vbox.setSpacing(5);
        vbox.setPadding(new Insets(10, 0, 0, 10));
        vbox.getChildren().addAll(label, table, hb);

        ((Group) scene.getRoot()).getChildren().addAll(vbox);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static class Person {

        private final SimpleStringProperty firstName;
        private final SimpleStringProperty lastName;
        private final SimpleStringProperty email;

        private Person(String fName, String lName, String email) {
            this.firstName = new SimpleStringProperty(fName);
            this.lastName = new SimpleStringProperty(lName);
            this.email = new SimpleStringProperty(email);
        }

        public String getFirstName() {
            return firstName.get();
        }

        public void setFirstName(String fName) {
            firstName.set(fName);
        }

        public String getLastName() {
            return lastName.get();
        }

        public void setLastName(String fName) {
            lastName.set(fName);
        }

        public String getEmail() {
            return email.get();
        }

        public void setEmail(String fName) {
            email.set(fName);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, too you and fabian! Helped me out a bunch